# Executing JavaScript code retrieved via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've condensed my problem into the following sample code:

```
<?php 
if($_GET['ajax']){
    echo '  <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("test alert");
                var newdata="Hello Again!";
                $(container).append(newdata);
            </script>';
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var container = document.getElementById('testdiv');
            var data = 'Hello World' ;
            $(container).append(data);
        });
        function goAjax(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/test.php/?ajax=1',
                type: "POST",
                data: {"xxx":1},
                success: function(data){
                    $("#return").empty();
                    $("#return").append(data);
                }
            });
        };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="goAjax();">test</a>
        <div id="testdiv"></div>
        <div id="return"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is load in the JS script located at the top of the code into the web page and have it execute.

The `alert()` executes fine, but I cannot get `Hello Again!` to show up. It is not executing that part of the script.

Can someone help to explain why?

Note that the use of a reference defined earlier (`container`) is vital to my problem, and a workaround involving a direct reference does not solve things for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a lok at [`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), it does exactly what you want.

Comment: @try-catch-finally: Thanks for the suggestion, I did not know about that. Unfortunately, along with the script, there is other code I am loading in as well - so ideally I'm looking for a one-hit solution.

Comment: What does it mean, that you're loading other code as well? The request will return not only Javascript (e.g. data, text, html) or other script content you won't execute?

Comment: Yes, correct. `<script>` along with other static HTML code is being returned; I just wanted the script to execute directly so I only have to bring everything in once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that the `Hello Again` text is not displaying because the `container` variable referenced is not available globally. You are defining `container` as a local variable here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var container = document.getElementById('testdiv');
    var data = 'Hello World' ;
    $(container).append(data);
});
```

So, try defining `container` globally. Or simply re-select the `#testdiv` in your returned script (instead of referencing `container` at all).

For running the script, instead of messing with `<script>`s yourself, I'd definitely recommend just using [`jQuery.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

Comment: Yes, exactly correct on variable definition. In my example above, how exactly do I define `container` globally so that it can be used within the injected script?

Comment: @RC You can, instead of doing `var container = `, just do `window.container = `. Typically it's not a good idea to define variables globally but that's probably a topic for another day :D

Comment: James, perfect, thank you. Problem solved. This is for a small internal system with limited potential for disaster or security issues etc, so functionally this will work just fine for us.

Answer (score 0):

One way to that is to inject that script to DOM by using

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerText =  'code retrieved from ajax';
document.appendChild(script);
```

Other way is `jQuery.getScript()` from the jQuery.

Comment: And the third (and most dangerous) way is to `eval()` the code itself.

Comment: Thanks guys. As per my comment above, there is other code I am loading in as well (not just the script) - so ideally I'm looking for a one-hit solution where I can append a `<script>` tag and have it execute. Not sure why my reference `container` isn't being seen.

Comment: See this for more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167403/is-javascript-eval-so-dangerous