# Execute a string as a piece of HTML/javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

So, lets say I have a string defined in javascript:

```
   var s = "function();"
```

Can I execute the code if I know the value of the string?

And if yes, then can I have multiple commands inside a string? For instance:

```
   var k = "function(); a = a + 1;"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `eval()`... [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), and yes multiple statements will be executed. **BUT, it is generally a bad idea to use `eval`.** In most cases you can probably accomplish whatever you are trying to do without `eval`.

`eval` can be quite **dangerous if used with user supplied code**, such as something from a form or URL. It opens you up to [Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Just avoiding it is the best course of action, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13167699/778975) mentions, sanitizing input before putting it through `eval` is not at all straight forward and very error prone.

A couple of other less important problems with using `eval` are that it makes code hard to debug and it is slow. It makes it hard if not impossible for browsers to optimize and/or cache it like they do other code.

**Update**

I'm surprised I neglected to mention this when I originally answered this, but explicitly using the `eval` statement is not the only way `eval` can be invoked in JavaScript. Passing [code instead of a function reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Parameters) to `setTimeout` or `setInterval` will implicitly eval that code.

```
// This evals:
setTimeout("doSomething()", 1000);
// This does not eval:
setTimeout(doSomething, 1000); // also shorter :)
```

Although not exactly the same as `eval`, the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) also has [similar security concerns associated with it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Difference_between_Function_constructor_and_function_declaration).

```js
let xss = 'alert("XSS")';

// whatever is in the string passed to Function
// becomes the body of the function
let doSomething = new Function(xss);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
```

```html
<button>Do Something</button>
```

Just as with `eval`, care should be taken when using strings as input for `setTimeout`, `setInterval` or the `Function` constructor, especially if user input is going to be passed into them.

**Also see:**

- [How evil is eval](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)
- [Eval isn't evil, just misunderstood](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/)
- [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) (Several good answers here)
- [Dynamic languages strike back](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/05/dynamic-languages-strike-back.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()` to Evaluate/Execute JavaScript code/expressions:

```js
var k = "var a = 0; alert(a); a = a + 1; alert(a);"
eval(k);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `eval` **function** will evaluate a string that is passed to it.
it is **slow**. This is because the code to be evaluated must be parsed on the spot, so that will take some computing resources.