# Save string as code in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string in Javascript. What I need is to save it as code:

```
var string = "this.count++";
var func1 = {};
func1['f'] = string; // should be saved as executable code..
```

How can I do? I don't need `eval()`, cause I don't need to evaluate in this moment.

Comment: `var string = () => this.count++;var func1 = {};
func1['f'] = string();`

Comment: Are you asking how to create a function for later execution based on code in a string?  What is the context of "this" ?

Comment: @AlexK. actually this have no context.. I need to save it in an object.. in that object this have a context

Comment: **Why** do you think you need to do this? Because you almost certainly don't.

Comment: @PranavCBalan wich language is that? I tried it give me error!!

Comment: @granmirupa : ES6 arrow function

Comment: @PranavCBalan thanks it works on chrome

Comment: granmirupa - If @Pranav's answer worked for you, that's fundamentally different from what you actually asked and not at all what gurvinder372's answer says. gurvinder's answer is the answer to *what you asked*, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it works in sense it doesn't give error.. but is not the answer to my question

Comment: @granmirupa: Ah! Okay, I understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
new Function(string)
```

for example

```js
var string = "this.count++; console.log(1)";
new Function(string)();
```

**Note**: Using `Function` constructor (as with `eval`) you will be able to execute any arbitrary code which could be a **security risk** if it contains user-derived text. Not so much an issue if it's definitely the current user who entered it (they have other ways of running code on the page), but if you're running text from User A as code on User B's browser, that's a **massive** no-no.

Answer (score 1):

You could create `new Function()` object. Keep in mind that you should avoid this as much as possible, because **[new Function() and eval() are dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167403/is-javascript-eval-so-dangerous)**!

```
func1['f'] = new Function(string).
```

You can read about this more **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)**.