# Trying to find out the next tr button fa icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following a jQuery piece of code, I am trying to get the button icon which is inside the `<button>` of the next element which tells me if the icon is of trash type or something else so on that basis, I can write my logic

Trying it like this:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('td').eq($(this).index()-1).closest('button').html();
```

but I get this error:

and trying to find value of the next tr

```
<td>
<button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
```

Comment: Please show HTML and expected output - you can click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: your code is finding value of current button, i want to find value of either prev or next one

Comment: `next element` is very unclear given the code you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an working example

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
  console.log("next: " + $(this).closest('tr').next().find('td button').html());
  console.log("prev: " + $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td button').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: nice but how do i bring its result to true or false, should i do `eval`

Comment: @Jabbu What exactly do you mean? Do want to check if next button exists? And no, never use `eval` [here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167403/is-javascript-eval-so-dangerous)

Comment: figured out by adding a hasclass functionality so thanks