# Multiply in Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I need to multiply HTML values which contains two numbers like the following:

```html
<span class="elementClass">firstNumber / secondNumber</span>
<!-- for example -->
<span class="elementClass">2000 / 4000</span>
```

How do I get each number separately and multiply it for example by 2 and get value '4000 / 8000'.

Maybe something like this:

```
let m = $('.elementClass')[0].innerHTML;
$('.elementClass')[0].innerHTML = m * 2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've got the innerHTML you need to get those 2 values from there as you already wrote.

`let first_number = 0, second_number = 0`

`let tmp = $('.elementClass')[0].innerHTML;`

`tmp = tmp.trim() // remove spaces from the innerHTML string.`

Once we get the `innerHTML` without any `spaces`, we need to split it into 2 values as per their separator.

In the above example `/` is a separator and then we can write the codes like this :

`let ary = tmp.split('/')`

`first_number = ary[0]`

`second_number = ary[1]`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to get all digits before and after `SPACE / SPACE`.

```js
let numbers = document.querySelector('.elementClass').innerHTML.split(/(\d*) \/ (\d*)/);

console.log('First: ' + 2 * numbers[1]); // numbers[1] is 2000
console.log('Seccond: ' + 2 * numbers[2]); // numbers[2] is 4000
```

```html
<span class="elementClass">2000 / 4000</span>
```

The regex explained:

```
(\d*) \/ (\d*)
  -- ----  --
  |   |     |_____ match all digits
  |   |
  |   |____________ match space / space
  |   
  |________________ match all digits
```

Find more information and explanation about the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/GkbHPm/1

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = $('.elementClass')[0].innerHTML.split("/");
first = parseInt(numbers[0].replace(/ /g, ''));
second = parseInt(numbers[1].replace(/ /g, ''));

multiplier = 2;

first = first * multiplier;
second = second * multiplier;

$('.elementClass')[0].innerHTML = String(first) + ' / ' + String(second);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case there are other (or multiple operands), you could simply evaluate the expression found in the innerHTML.
For example,

```
newValue = eval($('.elementClass')[0].innerHTML);
$('.elementClass')[0].innerHTML = newValue;
```

[View the JSFiddle Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/87bgf4sp/1/).

This example also uses [eval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp). You should read why [this is potentially dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167403/is-javascript-eval-so-dangerous) before using it.